# Cannot get the gerrit SAML plugin to work with existing accounts

Tags: saml, saml-2.0, gerrit

I am running gerrit 3.2.8 and need to switch the auth to okta.  I installed the saml plugin https://gerrit.googlesource.com/plugins/saml/ and configured the okta IDP.  From a saml point of view, everything looks fine - I can see a valid signin with attributes, etc.

The problem I see is, the saml/okta auth is successful, but the gerrit/plugin code always tries to create a new account, and upon finding there is already an account with this email, fails with the error forbidden.

After poking around in the gerrit and saml code, it appears to me that this plugin will not work for existing accounts.  The authentication relies on the existence a "saml" external ID in the users account.  And afaict, the only way this ever gets created is when an account gets saml authenticated and created.

So, 2 questions:

1. Are my findings correct?  This does not work for existing accounts.
2. If so, how do I get around this?

I thought about trying to make some updates in the All-Users repo concerning external id refs, but in the version of gerrit I am using it appears those back doors have been closed.